# Retrieving AMQP routing key information using pika

Tags: python, amqp, pika

New to RabbitMQ and I am trying to determine a way in which to retrieve the routing key information of an AMQP message.  Has anyone really tried this before?  I am not finding a lot of documentation that explicitly states how to query AMQP using pika (python).

This is what I am trying to do:

basically I have a Consumer class, for example:

`channel.exchange_declare(exchange='test', type='topic')
 channel.queue_declare(queue='topic_queue',auto_delete=True)
 channel.queue_bind(queue='topic_queue', exchange='test', routing_key = '#')`

I set up a queue and I bind to an exchange and all the routing_keys (or binding keys I suppose) being passed through that exchange.

I also have a function:

`def amqmessage(ch, method, properties, body):
       channel.basic_consume(amqmessage, queue=queue_name, no_ack=True)
       channel.start_consuming()`

I think that the routing_key should be "method.routing_key" from the amqmessage function but I am not certain how to get it to work correctly.

Comment: Your question shows lack of researches. Pika has not only a awesome documentation, a lot of examples but also direct answer to your question on it's github page https://github.com/pika/pika (see second example).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but that didn't quite help me. My definition of research and your definition of research are two different things.  Please don't judge.  I am new to python and if the answer is hidden in python code it is incredibly difficult for me to figure out and I will say it is not "explicitly stated" because to me, that is the truth.  I also am not finding this question being answered on stackoverflow, if it has already been answered please point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: Look on the page I gave you the link to for strings `for method_frame, properties, body in channel.consume('test'):`. From `method_frame` you can get `routing_key`, which is obvious if you have read official pika doc, especially this on - https://pika.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.13/examples/blocking_consumer_generator.html.

Comment: tl;dr Being newcomer to something is normal and no one (I hope) judge you (but someone downvoted, but don't care about points). What I tried to say you is that you stopped just in one step before your answer.

Comment: The page you suggest does not exist...thanks anyway, will try and see if I can find that document.

Comment: Sorry, it get garbaged somehow - http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/blocking_consumer_generator.html.

Comment: Zaq...Found a page: [BlockingChannel.basic_get](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/blocking_basic_get.html) I think I want the first tuple that this returns, need to play with this some more...

Answer (score 3):

I would like to write the answer down because it this question was before the documentation on google.

`def amqmessage(ch, method, properties, body):
       channel.basic_consume(amqmessage, queue=queue_name, no_ack=True)
       channel.start_consuming()`

The routing key can be found with:`method.routing_key`